# xsl : transform text to xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a text 2 xml transformation,
I need to transform to following plain text into an xml

```
[header]
CODE VEND = ABCD
TYPE = ORDER
CL CDE = ABDEFGH
CL INV = ABDEFGH
DAT CDE = 03022020
EMAIL = abcd@ .fr
NO CDE = 0000042268
DAT LIV = 03022020
TYP CDE = CDE SPECIALE
NBLIN = 1
CONTRM = ABDEFGH
CL LIV = ABDEFGH
[LINE]
REF VEN = DEFGH
EAN = 123456789
QTE = 1
REF CUST = "AZERTYUOP      "
[end]
```

my current xsl is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="txt-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="txt-uri" as="xs:string" select="'linktofile'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="text2xml">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="unparsed-text($txt-uri, $txt-encoding)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="entries" as="node()*">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$txt" regex="\r\n?|\n">
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([^;]*).*=([^;]*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <entry>
                <nom><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))"/>
                </nom>
                <valeur><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))"/>
                </valeur>
                <!--text2><xsl:value-of 
                  select="normalize-space(regex-group(3))"/></text2-->
              </entry>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <results>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$entries" group-by="nom">
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="current-group()[1]/nom,current-group()/*[not(self::nom)]"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am able to split the data on the equal sign,
What I would need is the following:

```
<CODE_VEND>ABCD</CODE_VEND>
<TYPE>ORDER</TYPE>
<CL_CDE>ABCD</CL_CDE>
```

+ group the header (between [HEADER] and CL_LIV) data based on `<NO_CDE>0000042268</NO_CDE>`

Can you help me on that,

Thanks

**Updated description**
Source

```
[ENTETE]
CODE VEND = MONH
TYPE = COMMANDE
CL CDE = ABDCDEFG
CL INV = HIJIKL
DAT CDE = 03022020
EMAIL = abcd@.fr
NO CDE = 0000042268
DAT LIV = 03022020
TYP CDE = CDE SPECIALE
NBLIN = 3
CONTRM = ABDCDEFG
CL LIV = ABDCDTERK
[LIGNE]
REF FOU = REFVEN1
GENCOD = EAN11111111
QTE = 1
REF CLI = "XXXXXXXXXXX      "
[LIGNE]
REF FOU = REFVEN2
GENCOD = EAN2222222
QTE = 1
REF CLI = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY      "
[LIGNE]
REF FOU = REFVEN3
GENCOD = EAN333333
QTE = 1
REF CLI = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ      "
[FIN]
```

target

```
<ORDER>
    <CODE_VEND>MONH</CODE_VEND>
    <TYPE>COMMANDE</TYPE>
    <CL_CDE>ABDCDEFG</CL_CDE>
    <CL_INV>HIJIKL</CL_INV>
    <DAT_CDE>03022020</DAT_CDE>
    <EMAIL>abcd@.fr</EMAIL>
    <NO_CDE>0000042268</NO_CDE>
    <DAT_LIV>03022020</DAT_LIV>
    <TYP_CDE>CDE SPECIALE</TYP_CDE>
    <NBLIN>3</NBLIN>
    <CONTRM>ABDCDEFG</CONTRM>
    <CL_LIV>ABDCDTERK</CL_LIV>
    <LINE>
        <REF_VEN>REFVEN1</REF_VEN>
        <EAN>EAN11111111</EAN>
        <QTE>1</QTE>
        <REF_CLI>XXXXXXXXXXX</REF_CLI>
    </LINE>
    <LINE>
        <REF_VEN>REFVEN2</REF_VEN>
        <EAN>EAN2222222</EAN>
        <QTE>1</QTE>
        <REF_CLI>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</REF_CLI>
    </LINE>
    <LINE>
        <REF_VEN>REFVEN3</REF_VEN>
        <EAN>EAN333333</EAN>
        <QTE>1</QTE>
        <REF_CLI>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</REF_CLI>
    </LINE>
</ORDER>
```

...

Comment: You can't have a space in an element name, as you seem to want with `<CL CDE>`. So it is not clear what you want to achieve there. I am also not sure what kind of grouping you want to achieve, you seem to transform each line of the plain text intro an `entry` element with `nom` and `valeur` children, perhaps show us the intermediary structure you create there and then the "grouping" result you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  the space is a typo (fixed now), you are right. the file is divided by 1 header (from [header] to NBLIN, the part below is repeated several times, it is related to lines.

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly you are struggling with, if you don't want `<nom>CODE VEND</nom><valeur>ABCD</valeur>` then it should be easy to create `<CODE_VEND>ABCD</CODE_VEND>` with `<xsl:element name="replace(normalize-space(regex-group(1)), ' ', '_')"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))"/></xsl:element>` instead. But I have no idea where the `<CL_CDE>ABCD</CL_CDE>` comes from, the input would suggest `<CL_CDE>ABDEFGH</CL_CDE>`, no? For the grouping you need to explain exactly which output you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have uploaded a full example, I hope it clarifies, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 one could approach that as a grouping task, grouping the lines from the text files with `group-starting-with`, then breaking up each line into an element could be achieved with `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:param name="txt-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="txt-uri" as="xs:string" select="'linktofile'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="text2xml">

    <xsl:variable name="lines" as="xs:string*" select="unparsed-text-lines($txt-uri, $txt-encoding)"/>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with=".[. = '[ENTETE]']">
        <ORDER>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-starting-with=".[. = '[LIGNE]']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". = '[LIGNE]'">
                        <LINE>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="(current-group() => tail()) ! analyze-string(., '(.+) = (.+)')"/>
                        </LINE>                        
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="(current-group() => tail()) ! analyze-string(., '(.+) = (.+)')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ORDER>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:match">
      <xsl:element name="{replace(normalize-space(fn:group[@nr = 1]), ' ', '_')}">
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(fn:group[@nr = 2])"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample with text data inlined at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsy.

XSLT 3 is available with Saxon 9.8 or later or AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later.

If you only have XSLT 2 you could of course use the first step you have to transform text lines into XML elements and then use a similar `group-starting-with` on those elements. And of course instead of `analyze-string` as a function you could stick with `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: I have paste your all code into my env, the following error is raised: XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 18 on line 54 in {(current-group() => tail}:, any idea why it is errored?

Comment: As I said, I have used XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 as supported by Saxon 9.8 or later.

Comment: Martin Honnen, thank you your solution is working perfectly. I still have to adapt it to my own case (saxon 9HE): I have to remove the tail(), arrow function (=>)

Comment: @Komagain, which version of Saxon 9 HE is that? As I said, the used constructs are XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 which Saxon supports since 2017 and the release 9.8 and newer ones. As for adaption, `tail(expression)` is `subsequence(expression, 2)`. The arrow operator is simply syntactic sugar to unnest function calls so `current-group() => tail()` can be written as `tail(current-group())`

Comment: Martin Honnen, I have read your version, I have already approuved your answer :). My version should be 9.5 I guess